# Send event target inside data-bind click html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I can't send event target when send parameter in data-bind.

```
<button class="tablinks" data-bind="click:$root.notify.bind(this, 1, 'foo');" id="defaultOpen">PRINSIPAL</button>

self.notify = function (str, id, e) {
    if (!e) e = window.event;
    console.log(str + id);
    console.log(e.currentTarget);
});
```

The result of `currectTarget` is `undefined`. But when not using parameter this will working. example working:

```
<button class="tablinks" data-bind="click:$root.notify;" id="defaultOpen">PRINSIPAL</button>

self.notify = function (data, e) {
    console.log(e.currentTarget);
});
```

The output will be `<button class="tablinks" data-bind="click:$root.notify;" id="defaultOpen">PRINSIPAL</button>`

How to get event target when I'm parsing multiple parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Knockoutjs` , `event` is always passed as the last argument to the event handler. So you can catch it there and use it like

```js
function vm(){
  this.notify = function (str, id, e,event) {
     
    console.log(event.currentTarget)
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.0.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<button class="tablinks" data-bind="click:$root.notify.bind(this, 1, 'foo');" id="defaultOpen">PRINSIPAL</button>
```